# Java applet destroy() with showConfirmDialog

Tags: java, swing, dialog, applet, joptionpane

I'm doing some bug fixing on an old applet, but I'm running into issues with applets `destroy()` being called while there is a confirm dialog open (`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`). Basically, If there is a dialog box open, and the browser window is closed, the dialog box stays open, and the applets keep running in the background (not in a browser window). Is there a way to close all the dialog boxes and ensure that all applets are destroyed when the browser window is closed?

EDIT: ok, to clarify, this confirm dialog is being opened in a thread that the applet starts. However, it has the instance of the applet that started it, and the confirm dialog is being started with `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(applet_instance, ...)` This should mean that the user is unable to access the browser while the dialog is up. However, I can still close the window behind the dialog, and this kills the applet, but not the thread that opened the dialog. How would I go about killing all the threads when the window is closed, or how do I actually stop the user from closing the window without acknowledging the dialog first?

EDIT 2: I just tried to make the dialog in the applet itself, at the end of the `start()` method. This results in a dialog right when the applet loads, but I can still close the browser window behind the dialog and the dialog remains...

Comment: If you have not seen [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323773/how-to-kill-java-applet-beeing-in-a-loop-when-browser-is-closed) yet, it might be worth a look.

Comment: Yup, I saw that. I have a number of threads, but each has a kill function and should be killed appropriately. The dialog box is being called from a thread that isn't the applet, but I kill it when the applet is destroyed. However, it seems that closing the window in this case is not calling the applets destroy in the first place...

Comment: does your code  call the destroy method ?

Comment: *"while there is a confirm dialog open (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog"*  What is the parent of that dialog?  Make the applet the component on which it is based and the user should not be able to access the browser until it is dismissed..

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*The dialog box is being called from a thread that isn't the applet*"?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, please see the edit above.